# Where is the onMeasure() default code located?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-view, onmeasure

I understand that you can override the `onMeasure()` method to make custom measurements and that the `onMeasure()` method is called when you call the `view.measure()` method

If I call `view.measure` as shown below,  it will still work even if I don't override the `onMeasur`e method?   That means there is a default version of the `onMeasure` method that exists,  where is it located?

i don't exactly know what is going on when the measure method is called on a `View` object, the documentation does not tell much about this.  is if i am not overriding the `onMeasure()` method i have to look at the code for the already defined `onMeasure()` method to find out what it is doing.   the scary part is calling measure and not knowing what is going on under the hood.

I want to see it and can't find the code

```
 view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the AOSP for the codes view.onmeasure [view.onmeasure](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#onMeasure)